# Amazon Alexa Skills - Card in mobile app creation

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make a Card in mobile application, which is attached to Amazon Account and current skill.

Is it enough just call EMIT function with 'tellWithCard'? Like in example:

```
that.emit(':tellWithCard', "Thank you for your visit", "Store Name", "Some description")
```

I tried all of this functions separately, but doesn't work for me:

```
that.emit(':tellWithCard', message, "Store Name", description)
that.emit(':tellWithLinkAccountCard', message, "Store Name", description)

that.emit(':askWithCard', message, "Store Name", description)
that.emit(':askWithLinkAccountCard', message, "Store Name", description)
```

Is there any additional functions should be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is all you need.

Here is an example:
(Taken from the [README](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) of the original repo)

```
var cardTitle = 'Hello World Card';
var cardContent = 'This text will be displayed in the companion app card.';

var imageObj = {
    smallImageUrl: 'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png',
    largeImageUrl: 'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png'
};

this.emit(':tellWithCard', 'lalalala', cardTitle, cardContent, imageObj);
```

Do verify that from the Service Simulator you should get a response like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
  "outputSpeech": {
    "type": "SSML",
    "ssml": "<speak> lalalala </speak>"
  },
  "card": {
    "text": "This text will be displayed in the companion app card.",
    "title": "Hello World Card",
    "image": {
      "smallImageUrl": "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png",
      "largeImageUrl": "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png"
    },
    "type": "Standard"
  },
  "shouldEndSession": true
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

But please keep in mind that testing from the Service Simulator won't create the actual card within the Alexa app. For this you need to use a device.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I tried in this way, on device as well. Device was connected to the same account... But probably I doing something wrong,  not on this part of implementation. Do you have any other ideas what can affect Card sending?

Comment: Do you get this kind of answer in the service simulator?

Comment: Yes. I receive answer in "text" simulator, in https://echosim.io/ simulator, on "Test" execution, on real device as a voice message, and even receiving record via HTTP POST to external system (made for test, called before emit)

Night be there some special configurations in Amazon account?

Comment: Now I creating absolutely new Lambda for other functionality, might be I avoid such mistake. Keep everyone in update.

Comment: @user2960820 Nothing special needs to be done in the amazon account/app.